# Sending message in telegram bot with images

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I have telegram-bot code on php, and reply messages sending by `replyWithMessage` method.

All command here:

```
 $this->replyWithMessage(['text' => $item['title']. "\n\n" . $url]);
```

How can i add some preview image before text?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `/sendphoto` and set the `caption`which appears under an image.
 
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto

Comment: It has a 0-200 characters constrain. https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto

Comment: Photo caption (may also be used when resending photos by file_id), 0-1024 characters

Answer (score 9):

No, You CAN send a text that contains photo in one single message. Telegram allows you do this but that the way is kinda tricky.

1. Using https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage method, set option `disable_web_page_preview` => `false`
2. In your `text` data put an image link with invisible character(s) inside your message text.

Example:

```
$message = <<<TEXT
*** your content ***
*** somewhere below (or above) a link to your image with invisible character(s) ***
<a href="https://www.carspecs.us/photos/c8447c97e355f462368178b3518367824a757327-2000.jpg"> ‏ </a>
TEXT;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: multipart/form-data']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage');
$postFields = array(
    'chat_id' => '@username',
    'text' => $message,
    'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
    'disable_web_page_preview' => false,
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
if(!curl_exec($ch))
    echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: an actual information is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43705283/4213969

tl dr: 
1) put `&#8205;` inside a-tag instead of whitespaces 
2) set `disable_web_page_preview=true`

Comment: @Vladimir, thanks for the heads up, works flawlessly

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using markdown too:

```
var axios = require('axios');

axios.post('https://api.telegram.org/'+telegram_bot_id+'/sendMessage', { chat_id: _target_telegram_channel, parse_mode: 'markdown', text: '[ ‏ ](https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B07NVCJ3V8?pf_rd_p=ba8c3f2e-eba5-4c79-9599-683af7a49dd1&pf_rd_r=XPRH5A07HN9W62DK1R84)' } )
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't send a text message that contains both image and text. However If your text contains URL, Telegram displays a preview of the web page by default.
Or you can send two message one after another or send a photo with caption.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is use [/sendPhoto with caption](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) (max len 1024 characters) and then will use [/sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage), where 4096 characters allowed