# Spring Boot(Java) Telegrambots 5.3.0 SendMessage with html, how to attach image in it?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I would like to put image(link) inside `html` and send it over with Telegram.
But when I try to put image inside html body it stops to work, that message won't be delivered after execution. I tried the approaches from this SO post: [How to send an Embedded Image along with text in a Message via Telegram Bot API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685619/how-to-send-an-embedded-image-along-with-text-in-a-message-via-telegram-bot-api/43705283#43705283)
. Sending html without image works. But it doesnt work with image, neither **disableWebPagePreview()** or `&#8205;` solves the problem. How to fix it?

```
SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        sendMessage.setParseMode(ParseMode.HTML);
        sendMessage.disableWebPagePreview();
        sendMessage.setChatId(chatId);
        sendMessage.enableHtml(true);
        String html = "<a href=\"https://www.carspecs.us/photos/c8447c97e355f462368178b3518367824a757327-2000.jpg\">&#8205;</a>";
        sendMessage.setText(html);
        executeAsync(message);
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```